# Sign in to ** to update application for that account

Tags: macos, mac-mini

So I somehow grabbed my parents USB thumb drive to install Mountain Lion. Now when I want to upgrade to Mavericks, its asking me to sign into my parents icloud account.

So I rebooted, did an Internet Recovery, and it installed a clean version of Mountain Lion. It's prompting me again still.

How can I re-associate my Mac Mini to my icloud account?

Answer (score 1):

these are sort of "nuke from orbit" directions; there's likely a less extreme way, but this should work:

- shutdown
- boot to single-user mode by holding down <kbd>⌘ command</kbd>-<kbd>s</kbd> on boot
- enter these commands at the console

  ```
  fsck -fy
  mount -uw /
  rm /var/db/.AppleSetupDone
  shutdown -r now
  ```
- run through the Setup Assistant creating a new administrator account